# Which ordinary index will this statement be used

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `a` int(255) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `b` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `c` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `d` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a`),
  KEY `b` (`b`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `c` (`c`(19)) USING BTREE,
  KEY `d` (`d`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='test';

insert test(a,b,c,d) values('1','1','1','1');
insert test(a,b,c,d) values('2','2','2','1');
insert test(a,b,c,d) values('3','3','3','1');
insert test(a,b,c,d) values('4','4','4','1');
```

I don't know which index the following SQL uses, but I know that Innodb engine only uses one index.

```
explain select * from test where b='2' and c='2' and d='2';
```

I executed the above sql in the mysql database, then this statement uses 'b index'. Are there any rules here? Or are there any rules for the optimizer, but it is used here?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, MySQL would choose the index on the column that is most restrictive -- that is, the one that chooses the fewest rows.

But for your query, you want an index that has all three columns, `b`, `c`, and `d` in any order.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "ordinary".  Multi-column indexes are as "ordinary" as single column indexes.

Comment: Thank you all . .Someone ask me about this question and I thought this question all the night . This table only creates three 'ordinary' indexs. Is there an optimizer to calculate the most restrictive and the fewest rows ?

Comment: @Eric . . . MySQL (such as other databases) keeps statistics on indexes.  You might want to start investigating with `analyze`:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html.

Comment: This ordinary index seems (key b (b) using btree). Multi column index seems (key inx_bcd (b,c,d) using btree).

Answer (score 0):

For

```
where b='2' and c='2' and d='2';
```

have

```
INDEX(b,c,d) -- with the columns in any order
```

Another issue.  Don't use "prefix" indexing without a good reason:

```
  KEY `c` (`c`(19)) USING BTREE,
```

It is mostly useless.

Here are some *guidelines*:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql